# UIImageView's UIImage gets set to nil after selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, sdwebimage

I have been trying to solve this problem for over an hour now, and am no closer than before, despite breaking lots of things and then fixing them again, with no change to the original issue.

I have absolutely no idea which parts of my code are relevant, please tell me if you need additional parts.

Here is my `configureCell:forAnime` method

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forAnime:(Anime *)anime {
[cell.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[df setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

if ([anime.fetched boolValue]) {
    [(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:401] sd_setImageWithURL:[anime getURLWithServer:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] URLForKey:@"imageServer"]]];
    [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:402] setText:anime.romajiName];
    [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:403] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ episode%@", anime.type, anime.numberOfEpisodes, [anime.numberOfEpisodes isEqualToNumber:@1]?@"":@"s"]];
    [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:404] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [df stringFromDate:anime.airDate], [df stringFromDate:anime.endDate]]];
}
else {
    [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:402] setText:@"Anime not yet loaded"];
    [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:403] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Anime ID: %@", anime.id]];
}
```

}

`sd_setImageWithURL:` is part of the `SDWebImage` framework which I got on GitHub.

Now when I run my app, everything populates perfectly, the images are already cached from previous runs and load instantly. [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0dpf5zwjwtil2h/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2022%20Jan%202015%2014.12.49.png?dl=0)

When I click (since I'm running in the simulator) a cell gets selected, the UIImage (apparently) gets set to nil, disappears, and the AutoLayout moves all text all the way to the left. [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fo476qnwgsiqp4k/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2022%20Jan%202015%2014.14.33.png?dl=0)

This method gets called when I select a cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
Anime *selectedAnime = [self.animeController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

AnimeDetailController *detailController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AnimeDetail"];
[detailController setRepresentedObject:selectedAnime];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailController animated:YES];
}
```

**Clarification**: This is `self.animeController`

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *animeController;
```

Also, while actually holding down on the cell, it gets a dark background, showing it is selected, and the image comes back and the layout is as it should be.

I am at a total loss as to what could cause this behaviour, please help.

**Update:** I just found a REALLY awesome looking feature of Xcode called "Debug View Hierarchy" which shows, as the name implies, the view hierarchy in a visual way, and here I can see that the cell where the `UIImageView` has disappeared has actually shifted to the left, so that the edge of the screen is flush with the left edges of my `UILabel`s. Maybe this can help someone in understand how I can make it NOT do that.

**Update:** Now I have tried to log the x coordinate for the frame of my cell's content views, since they are being moved, and indeed, using this code:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
Anime *selectedAnime = (tableView == self.tableView) ? [self.animeController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] : [self.resultsController.animeController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"Will deselect \"%@\" Content view frame origin x: %f", selectedAnime.romajiName, [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].contentView.frame.origin.x);
return indexPath;
}
```

I have found out that my content views are being moved 87 points in negative direction, to the left. I have also found out that `tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` is always being called twice for some reason, and that the incorrect frames are only observable in the deselection callbacks, so `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`. In the selection callbacks, the x values are 0, as they should be, but that doesn't mean that the content views are where they should be, they still appear shifted.

Comment: If you select a cell, its selected background view will become visible. I think you have added the image to the cell's view instead of its _content_ view (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html).

Comment: I have created this cell in an external xib file which gets registered like this: `[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"AnimeCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];`. I don't think I could have added it to anything but the content view in InterfaceBuilder, I would not know how to, and in the hierarchy of the xib file, the `UIImageView` is clearly below "Content View".

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is is in [self.animeController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]. You should initialize object for that selected row. So you should write [self.animeController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath.]

Comment: I do not think so, I have edited my post, self.animeController is a `NSFetchedResultsController`